# SP 2013 and InfoPath 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath

Must you have InfoPath 2013 to use it to customize list forms on SharePoint 2013? I'm using InfoPath 2010 with SP 2013.

When I click customize form, I get the browser going to a funky website address (`ms-...:http://`) and then a page not found. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath is not required.  You have different options with the Browser interface, SharePoint Designer, and Visual Studio.

You do however need InfoPath installed to make use of the "Customize Form" button in the ribbon - as this is expected to open in InfoPath.

Create a test list and then open the list in SharePoint Designer.  You will see the forms listed (Display, Edit, New) and you can open all of these in Edit mode and make changes.  You can also copy or create new pages here and then associate them with the appropriate list action.

For simple things or adding JavaScript or CSS to a page you can just edit the page in the browser and add other web parts like the content editor web part.

The third option is Visual Studio - this is the hammer, and generally you are probably going to be deploying a solution which includes your column and list definitions, list instance, and custom forms all packaged up as a solution or app.